# How to record a slide show in windowed mode in Powerpoint 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to use the builtin functions for recording a slide show and saving it as a video in MS PowerPoint 2010.
However, when I start the recording, the slide show switches to fullscreen, which is a problem for me.
I have some notes prepared in a separate document. I would like to record the show in a window, so that I can look at my notes in another window at the same time.
Is there a way do this?

(There is one setting which might seem relevant, but on closer inspection seems not to be. Clicking on "set up show", and then choosing "browsed by an individual", makes the show run in a window instead of fullscreen.
However, this seems to have no effect when *recording* a slide show, which is what I want.)

Please note that I don't have a second screen (or a printer), so to be able to se the notes while recording, I need to have them on the same screen.

Comment: I don't think that is possible, however if you add your notes to the presentation you can `Select Show notes pane on narration window`. See [Setting Up Slide Notes for Recording](https://community.articulate.com/series/how-do-i-create-my-first-course/articles/setting-up-slide-notes-for-recording). If this works for you let me know and I will write up a full answer.

Comment: @David, the link you provided discusses how to record videos with Powerpoint slides, but using another product (called Articulate Presenter) as well.
So for me, this is not really relevant, since I don't have this additional software.
Thanks anyway for your attempt to solve the problem,  it's much appreciated.